# Zeebus Puzzle #9

Tags: word, rebus

`C:\>solve
   for/rebus`

[image]

Get with the program...singularity is near.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll guess

> Robotics Engineer

as in

> "row-bot-ex" in "gin-ear"

Comment: That sounds like it! Did you utilise my partial answer @Bass?

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

> I think it's something to do in with the bots, followed by Engineer, from "In-GIN-EAR"